# ES6 destructuring assignment with more than one variable type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that returns 5 objects, and I would like to declare 4 of them using `const` and 1 of them using `let`. If I wanted all objects declared using `const` I could do:

```
const { thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5 } = yield getResults();
```

My current workaround is:

```
const results = yield getResults();

const thing1 = results.thing1;
const thing2 = results.thing2;
const thing3 = results.thing3;
const thing4 = results.thing4;

let thing5 = results.thing5;
```

But I'm wondering if destructuring assignment allows you to do this more elegantly.

No mention of this question on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) or on stackoverflow, as far as I can see.

Comment: Well just do `const {thing1, …} = results; let {thing5} = results;`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't possible to perform a destructure that initialises both `let` and `const` variables simultaneously. However the assignments to `const` can be reduced to another destructure:

```
const results = yield getResults()

const { thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4 } = results

let thing5 = results.thing5
```

Answer (score 6):

You still can use destructuring separately:

```
const results = yield getResults();
const { thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4} = results;
let   { thing5 } = results;
```

Alternatively, it is possible to do

```
let thing5;
const { thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4 } = { thing5 } = yield getResults();
```

but I guess that should rather be avoided to reduce the WTF/minute of your code.

Comment: I think the WTF/minute comment is a little harsh.  I feel that `const`s are a pretty legit way of reducing accidental mistakes and code smells.  If there's something here that really needs to be a mutable variable, I think "make them all variables" is a blunt instrument way of handling this.  I see your point, though...I might have written this to avoid the problem altogether, but the dev here is wise to use consts whenever possible.

Comment: @EthanBrown: I just meant that any style guide would forbid destructuring in nested assignments for good reason.